# Deploy Django app to Heroku AFTER DATABASE?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have deployed my django website to Heroku but since the website fields are dependent upon a database that is on my local machine. I've tried using Postgres but the database on Heroku doesn't populate with the data I need it to before the app runs. Has anyone experienced this? Do I need to use an exteranl database on AWS or something (in which case, what is the best way to do this?)

Comment: You can use the loaddata command from django to load you fixtures into the database.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata

Answer (score 0):

Use load data and dump data: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#loaddata

First dump the data on your local machine

```
python manage.py dumpdata ..other_options > data.json
```

add it to git and push to herkou

```
git add data.json
git commit -m "Added data"
git push heroku master
```

now on Heroku can use loaddata to load your data to database

```
heroku run python manage.py loaddata data.json
```

And your done.

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed a Django project on Heroku where I had data in models even after the deployment the data remained in the models. I worked on SQLite in production. Heroku works with Postgres but on deploying also my data remained safe. I just used git push heroku main